# Custom Connection Pool slow (JAVA)?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

For my project,we are asked to implement our own connectionpooling. We are NOT allowed to used PGPoolingDataSource from jdbc. When I used the jdbc pooling my program is very fast, with my own connection pool its unpredictable and much slower. My connection makes some tasks wait for a long time,something that doesnt happen with jdbc pooling.

I am using Arrayblockingqueue for my implementation of connection pool, I just create a pre said number of connections and then I let clients borrow and put them back.

I mean this seems to make sense to me,and it works. But its slow and sometimes the tasks take forever to get done,is there anyway I could improve it? Make it faster more reliable?

Comment: when taking the connection from pool, `if(c == null|| !c.isValid(2))` does this validation check return false generally and therefore it has to create a brand-new connection?

Comment: no but its just to make sure that if a connection is not valid/or null that we create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong data structure for storing connections `ArrayBlockingQueue` is the FIFO structure  which slowdown your processing, using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is the reasonable and faster choice for this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? You see I have many threads accessing this queue that has my connections,and naturally I want the request that asked the connection first to be served first right? So why is an arrayblockingqueue not ok?

Comment: Also I wanted to mention that your suggestion has really helped me, Im now studing concurrentlinkedqueues

Comment: the behaviour of arrayblockingqueue is correct but only 1 thread can access it at a time, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` allows multiple threads to access it same time.